# Is there a 'local scope' animation definition in CSS?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, scope

Today I was having a hard time to find out a bug and then it turns out that one of my animation name was the exactly same with a bootstrap animation and it was overriding it.
So, in my example I've defined

```
@keyframes fadeIn {
 // something different than bootstrap one
}
```

Since fadeIn was already defined in bootstrap this definition was overriding that. So, I thought it would be cool if we can define animations in 'local scope' or so but I couldn't find any results on web. Is there a thing like that or does anyone have any suggestion about what can be done while naming animations to be on the secure side?

Comment: don't use common names, try using your own or consider a kind of prefix like `murat_fadeIn`

Comment: You can rewrite the same `@keyframes` in your style.css file and that will override the original one. Otherwise, you need to rename your animation to something like `my-fadeIn` and then call that animation where you want. There's no local space for such scenarios